# How to display the skype user photo from HTTP Response using UCWA API?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10-universal, ucwa

I am working on Universal Windows Applications, in my current project I used Unified Communications Web API (UCWA) to display the skype user status it's working fine but when I am trying to display the skype user photo at that time I got stuck.

I followed below link to display the photo 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/ucwa/getmyphoto

I got response code of 200 OK for my GET request but I don't know how to display the image from my response.

Please tell me how to resolve it.

-Pradeep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got Result, After getting HTTP Response then I am converting those response content to stream type by using this below line.

```
var presenceJsonStr = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
```

This is the code to display the image

```
 var photo = await AuthenticationHelper.Photo();
// Create a .NET memory stream.
                var memStream = new MemoryStream();

                // Convert the stream to the memory stream, because a memory stream supports seeking.
                await photo.CopyToAsync(memStream);

                // Set the start position.
                memStream.Position = 0;

                // Create a new bitmap image.
                var bitmap = new BitmapImage();

                // Set the bitmap source to the stream, which is converted to a IRandomAccessStream.
                bitmap.SetSource(memStream.AsRandomAccessStream());

                // Set the image control source to the bitmap.
                imagePreivew.ImageSource = bitmap;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you put an Accept header specifying an image type, you should be able to look at the Content-Length header to determine if the user has an image set on the server.  If the length is zero you should consider providing a default image to be displayed.  If not, I would suggest taking a look at [Convert a Bitmapimage into a Byte Array and Vice Versa in UWP Platform](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/convert-a-bitmapimage-into-a-byte-array-and-vice-versa-in-uwp-platform) as you should treat the response body as a byte array with its length defined by the Content-Length header.

If for some reason no Accept header was provided, the response body is not an image/* type, and looks like a string then you might be dealing with a Base64 encoded image.  This case should be much less likely to deal with, but if you need advice I would suggest looking at [Reading and Writing Base64 in the Windows Runtime](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2014/11/reading-and-writing-base64-in-windows.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the URL generated for the user photo resource. Just set the URL of the image as the source of the Image container. You application would load it automatically.